# SwiftUI crashes due to deleted CoreData object

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI application, that updates views based on fetched CoreData objects, like so:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        VStack(alignment:.leading) {
            TaskProgressBar(model: ProgressModel(frequency: Int(task.frequency), deadline: task.deadline))
        }
    }
}
```

The app crashes because task.frequency becomes unexpectedly nil, when I delete the CoreData object:

```
func deleteTasks(_ tasks: [Task]) {
    for task in tasks {
        persistenContainer.viewContext.delete(task)
    }
    
    do {
        try persistenContainer.viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to save context after task deletion")
    }
}
```

I was able to fix it by calling `save()` asynchronously, but I am just wondering if that is the right solution? Is there a race condition and could my app still potentially crash, if saving asynchronously?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. All I can say and that wherever you are forcing `!` you shouldn't, you check for `nil`instead and present something else for that one frame.

Comment: Also, the exact error at the time of the crash is important as well.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped. I have custom core data classes, where frequency is a non-optional, since it is not optional in my core data model. But I guess it can still be nil temporarily while the object is being deleted. I did not think of this as force unwrapping initially, since no "!" is actually used.